# how to setup domain to Sub-folder as root domain withing showing sub-folder afterward?

Tags: cpanel, magento-1.9

I hope all are doing great. I need help from you guys. Could you please help to make sub-folder as a root folder for pointing the domain.

My domain is (simple.com) and its pointing to Public_html but I want to point sub-folder as root directory.

Public_html(www.simple.com)
Public_html/test1 (www.simple.com/test1)

I want to get all the content from sub-folder in main domain.
Like:
Public_html/test1 -->www.simple.com

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the package that your cPanel account is using allows Addon Domains I would recommend that you **contact your hosting provider and request that they change your primary domain**. After that add your (current) domain as an Addon with the desired Directory Root.

If not you can use an .htaccess rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```